# How do I localise a data-bound string property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-binding

I have a number of CompareValidators being declared inside ItemTemplates, like this:

```
<asp:CompareValidator
    runat="server"
    ID="ValueMinValidator"
    Display="Dynamic"
    Text="*"
    ForeColor="Red"
    ErrorMessage='<%# Eval("Description") + " below minimum " + Eval("Minimum") %>'
    Tooltip='<%# Eval("Description") + " below minimum " + Eval("Minimum") %>'
    ControlToValidate="Value"
    ValueToCompare='<%# Eval("Minimum") %>'
    Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
    Type="Double"
    Enabled='<%# Eval("Minimum") != null %>' meta:resourcekey="ValueMinValidatorResource1"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

The error message and tooltip properties are currently combining bound data values with string fragments to build the appropriate validation feedback. I'd like to localise these validation messages, while still retaining the data binding to the other item properties. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You should also consider using "Resources" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx

Comment: @GlennFerrie I'm already using implicit local Resources for my other localised text. I'm not sure how to embed/reference Resources in a Data Binding expression though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a binding expression that used string.Format and ASP.NET's autogen'd strongly-typed Resource class, to localize the error messages within the binding expressions. It turns out you can access those classes (and also TemplateControl.GetGlobalResource and TemplateControl.GetLocalResource) within the context of a binding expression. Since I didn't need two-way binding, this is sufficient.

Sample configuration:

```
<asp:CompareValidator
    runat="server"
    ID="ValueMinValidator"
    Display="Dynamic"
    Text="*"
    ForeColor="Red"
    ErrorMessage='<%# String.Format(Resources.MyResources.ValueLessThanMinimum, Eval("Description"), Eval("Minimum", "{0:"+ Eval("Format") + "}")) %>'
    Tooltip='<%# String.Format(Resources.MyResources.ValueLessThanMinimum, Eval("Description"), Eval("Minimum", "{0:"+ Eval("Format") + "}")) %>'
    ControlToValidate="Value"
    ValueToCompare='<%# Eval("Minimum") %>'
    Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
    Type="Double"
    Enabled='<%# Eval("Minimum") != null %>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

To implement this in a gridview, run the code on the OnRowDataBound event.:

HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvData_RowDataBound">
```

Code behind:

```
protected void gvData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataObject dataObject;
    CompareValidator valueMinValidator;
    string description, errorMessage;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        dataObject = (DataObject)e.Row.DataItem;
        valueMinValidator = (CompareValidator)e.Row.FindControl("ValueMinValidator");
        description = dataObject.Description;
        errorMessage = string.Format("{0} below minimum {1}", description, dataObject.Minimum); //localize dataObject.Minimum as needed
        valueMinValidator.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        valueMinValidator.ToolTip = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

While you are about it you can set any of the other properties in code behind. I find it gives you greater granularity.

Comment: How do I apply this in code behind to *every instance* of the CompareValidator? The CompareValidator is part of a ViewGrid ItemTemplate, so there will be multiple copies of it in the final HTML (one per row of the ViewGrid)

Comment: Please see the changed answer on how to implement it for every instance.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do is to cache the corresponding values into memory and match with the controls ID's and related session key (or whatever your base is) then assign the value.